# cartopy issues with south polar stereographic projection

Tags: python-xarray, cartopy

I am using xarray for the first time. My data has dimensions (time:1000,z_t:60, nlat:384, nlon: 320).  I am trying to plot ocean temp at a particular depth and time. This is successful on a platecarree projection, but when I try to switch to a south polar stereographic projection (using cartopy), my plot is wrong. The coastline of Antarctica does not match the data's outline of the continent.

First, the part of the code that works:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import xarray as xr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
filename = '/glade/scratch/mb/127kaH11/TEMP_annual_1000yr.nc'
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename)
```

Next, is the part where I try a new projection, and it does not seem to work properly:

```
# try to actually plot on SH projection now
# This is the map projection we want to plot *onto*
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

#choose a projection
proj = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
#ax.set_global()

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=proj)

ds.isel(time=999, z_t=33).TEMP.plot.pcolormesh(ax = ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent = ([-360, 0 , -90, -50], ccrs.PlateCarree())  

ax.coastlines()
```

The other question I have is the wedge of white in the second image.  Can someone please help me close this gap? In the past I've used add_cyclic_point but not sure if that applies here or how to use it properly.

Many thanks.

[Figure created from first snippet that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZFVa.png)

[Figure created from second snippet, that is causing problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgIBd.png)

Comment: In case it helps anyone, it looks like I needed to replace the x/y coordinates with a Lat/Lon from another file because these had NaN's and x/y arguments in pcolormesh cannot have non-finite values or be of type numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with masked values.